# Find specific li class of ul of div in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an html like below :

```
<div id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul navbar-nav="" mr-auto="">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="link-has-menu">Planning</a>
                 </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="link-has-menu">Destinations</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Bookings</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Travel information</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Promotions</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Partner Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

I want to select  and change the html of `Login`  li class. How can I do that ?
I tried `$("#navbarSupportedContent li:nth-child(5)")` but this is not yielding true result. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:you can find 5th li with `eq` selector in jquery like below

```
$('#navbarSupportedContentul li:eq(5) a').html('new text');
```

See below code

```js
$(function(){
  //$('#loginMenu').html('changed TEXT'); -- ID option not available so cannot use it
  $('#navbarSupportedContent ul li:eq(5) a').html('Changed TEXT');  
  //$('#navbarSupportedContent ul li a[data-target="#loginModal"]').html('Changed TEXT'); -- This will change two li values
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul navbar-nav="" mr-auto="">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="link-has-menu">Planning</a>
                 </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="link-has-menu">Destinations</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Bookings</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Travel information</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Promotions</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" id="loginMenu">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Partner Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @who ever downvoted - at least do some efforts to put comments that why answer is wrong and downvoted

Comment: Hi @Bhushan this command $('#navbarSupportedContent ul li[data-target="#loginModal"]').html('new text'); is not doing any changes.
Also, I cannot add div id as html is not under my control thats why I am using jquery to do the changes

Comment: it should `li a[data-target="#loginModal"]`, but this will change both login and partner login text, you will need some sort of identifier (id/class) for a better result

Comment: @n4m31ess_c0d3r, thanks for pointing out. I have corrected it in my post now and only proper solution is using `eq`

Comment: On code snippet it is working properly. did you change anything on html or is there any console errors?

Answer (score 1):

Use `eq(5)`:

```js
$("#navbarSupportedContent li").eq(5).find('a').text('changed value');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul navbar-nav="" mr-auto="">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="link-has-menu">Planning</a>
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="link-has-menu">Destinations</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Bookings</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Travel information</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Promotions</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Partner Login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to use `nth-child` then you need to use the value `6` as child count start from `1`:

```js
$("#navbarSupportedContent li:nth-child(6) a").text('changed value');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul navbar-nav="" mr-auto="">
          <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-has-menu">Planning</a>
           </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#" class="link-has-menu">Destinations</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Bookings</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Travel information</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Promotions</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Partner Login</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Ankit Agarwal, this command  $("#navbarSupportedContent li:nth-child(6)").html('changed value');
is removing other attributes of li element.

Comment: @AmbikaTewari what are those attributes that get removed?

Comment: href, data-toggle, data-target. It is becoming as <li>changed value</li> after i run the command.

Comment: @AmbikaTewari oops. I did not look that `a` tag there. Updated the answer. It should work now

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help:

**CHANGING CONTENT**

```js
$('#navbarSupportedContent li').eq(5).html('<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">New text here</a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul navbar-nav="" mr-auto="">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="link-has-menu">Planning</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="link-has-menu">Destinations</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Bookings</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Travel information</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Promotions</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Partner Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CHANGING/ADDING A CLASS**

```js
$('#navbarSupportedContent li').eq(5).addClass('newClass');
```

```css
.newClass a {
 color: red;
 font-weight: 700; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul navbar-nav="" mr-auto="">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="link-has-menu">Planning</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="link-has-menu">Destinations</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Bookings</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Travel information</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Promotions</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Partner Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the `<ul>` tag. I'm not too good at HTML & CSS, but try `$("#navbarSupportedContent ul li:nth-child(6)")` Also change the nth-child to **6**. Thanks to Rory McCrossan for pointing out the start index of nth-child is 1.

Comment: The base index of `nth-child` is `1`, so it should be `nth-child(6)`. Not sure that's enough justification for someone to downvote you, though

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#navbarSupportedContent ul a[data-target='#loginModal']").text("6e Login");
```

but there are two `li` who has `data-target` as `#loginModal`, so this command is changing text for both tabs.